# get parent child incremental paths in one group

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a way where  could get parent child paths in incremental form. Here is my input data

```
child  Parent   Society   Relation
B       A       YUM       ppp
C       B       YUM       qqq
D       C       YUM       ccc
A       None    YUM       ooo
A       None    PUM       ooo
Y       Z       YUM       qwe
W       Y       YUM       dfr
V       W       YUM       asd
Z       None    YUM       rtg
```

this is expected

```
childId   PATH                  level
A         ooo                    1
B         ooo|ppp                2
C         ooo|ppp|qqq            3
D         ooo|ppp|qqq|ccc        4
A         ooo                    1
Z         rtg                    1
Y         rtg|qwe                2
W         rtg|qwe|dfr            3
V         rtg|qwe|dfr|asd        4
```

As you can see, number of records are same, but getting respective incremental paths using relations and parent/child combination.

I'm not able to think any way, please share suggestions if possible

`Note:` would like to avoid functions like `sys_connect_by_path`, because I want to use this query on different platforms where sql with less functions are allowed

Update on `astentx 's answer`

this part will give 3 records

```
select
    society, child, relation, 1 as lvl
  from input
  where parent is null
```

output (`hier`)

```
SOCIETY CHILD   RELATION    LVL
YUM      A       ooo        1
PUM      A       ooo        1
YUM      Z       rtg        1
```

so when hier union all with recursive part, it will give below records after first iteration only

```
YUM A ooo       1    > from hier
YUM B ooo|ppp   2    >  came from inner join
and so on..this will become updated hier to join with input
```

so when inner join will happen between above updated hier with input, then <`> from hier`> from above output `wont take part again in inner join` ?

Comment: Check out oralce Hierarchical Queries, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm. you can use `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` to construct the path

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (child, parent, society, relation) as
  2    (select 'B', 'A' , 'YUM', 'ppp' from dual union all
  3     select 'C', 'B' , 'YUM', 'qqq' from dual union all
  4     select 'D', 'C' , 'YUM', 'ccc' from dual union all
  5     select 'A', null, 'YUM', 'ooo' from dual union all
  6     select 'A', null, 'PUM', 'ooo' from dual union all
  7     select 'Y', 'Z' , 'YUM', 'qwe' from dual union all
  8     select 'W', 'Y' , 'YUM', 'dfr' from dual union all
  9     select 'V', 'W' , 'YUM', 'asd' from dual union all
 10     select 'Z', null, 'YUM', 'rtg' from dual
 11    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 12  temp as
 13    (select society,
 14       child,
 15       ltrim(sys_connect_by_path (relation, ', '), ', ') path,
 16       level lvl
 17     from test
 18     start with parent is null
 19     connect by prior child = parent
 20    )
 21  select society, child, path, lvl
 22  from temp
 23  group by society, child, path, lvl
 24  order by society, lvl;

SOCIETY    CHILD PATH                        LVL
---------- ----- -------------------- ----------
PUM        A     ooo                           1
YUM        Z     rtg                           1
YUM        A     ooo                           1
YUM        Y     rtg, qwe                      2
YUM        B     ooo, ppp                      2
YUM        C     ooo, ppp, qqq                 3
YUM        W     rtg, qwe, dfr                 3
YUM        D     ooo, ppp, qqq, ccc            4
YUM        V     rtg, qwe, dfr, asd            4

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: is there any way we could avoid this function <<sys_connect_by_path>> ?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid it? Your problem is *hierarchical* and sys_connect_by_path is used there for the purpose you're looking for, so ... what's the point in avoiding it?

Comment: curios to learn how flexibly sql (without using much big functions like sys_connect_by_path  ) can be used to solve this problem

Comment: is there any other way of doing it ?

Comment: I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

You may use recursive CTE to build a hierarchy in Oracle as well as in other DBMS that support it.

> ```
> create table input (child, parent, society, relation) as 
>   select 'B', 'A' , 'YUM', 'ppp' from dual union all
>   select 'C', 'B' , 'YUM', 'qqq' from dual union all
>   select 'D', 'C' , 'YUM', 'ccc' from dual union all
>   select 'A', null, 'YUM', 'ooo' from dual union all
>   select 'A', null, 'PUM', 'ooo' from dual union all
>   select 'B', 'A' , 'PUM', 'ppp' from dual union all
>   select 'Y', 'Z' , 'YUM', 'qwe' from dual union all
>   select 'W', 'Y' , 'YUM', 'dfr' from dual union all
>   select 'V', 'W' , 'YUM', 'asd' from dual union all
>   select 'Z', null, 'YUM', 'rtg' from dual
> ```

> ```
> with hier(society, child, path, lvl) as (
>   /*Starting point*/
>   select
>     society, child, relation, 1 as lvl
>   from input
>   where parent is null
>   
>   union all
>   
>   /*Recursion step*/
>   select
>     hier.society,
>     input.child,
>     hier.path || ' -> ' || input.relation,
>     hier.lvl + 1
>   from hier
>     /*Inner join will reduce the number of rows added at each step*/
>     join input
>     on hier.society = input.society
>     and hier.child = input.parent
> )
> select *
> from hier
> order by society, path asc
> ```
>
> | SOCIETY | CHILD | PATH | LVL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | PUM | A | ooo | 1 |
> | PUM | B | ooo -> ppp | 2 |
> | YUM | A | ooo | 1 |
> | YUM | B | ooo -> ppp | 2 |
> | YUM | C | ooo -> ppp -> qqq | 3 |
> | YUM | D | ooo -> ppp -> qqq -> ccc | 4 |
> | YUM | Z | rtg | 1 |
> | YUM | Y | rtg -> qwe | 2 |
> | YUM | W | rtg -> qwe -> dfr | 3 |
> | YUM | V | rtg -> qwe -> dfr -> asd | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a1911643d6d1e6e59f5ed30c85bd23a0)*

Comment: cool..can you please share how its recursive part is working ? because at inner join only one entry seems to be coming out for every child whole parent is null

Comment: @Carol Recursive part refers to itself and processes all the rows from the previous iteration

Comment: can you please check update part in question ?